# Не применяется fontSize токен в ConfigProvider для компонента Typography из Ant-Design

Tags: reactjs, ui, ant-design

Использую Ant-Design 5.3.0.

Хочу изменить fontSize токен только для компонента Typography, но он почему-то не применяется. Если глобально токен изменить, то меняется - но тогда токен повлияет на все остальные компоненты, а мне этого не нужно

Вот код:

```
function App() {
return (
    <ConfigProvider
        theme={{
            token: {
                lineHeight: 1.2,
            },
            components: {
                Typography: {
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontSizeHeading1: 32,
                    fontSizeHeading2: 24,
                    fontSizeHeading3: 20,
                    fontSizeHeading4: 16,
                    fontSizeHeading5: 14,
                    lineHeightHeading1: 1.2,
                    lineHeightHeading2: 1.2,
                    lineHeightHeading3: 1.2,
                    lineHeightHeading4: 1.2,
                    lineHeightHeading5: 1.2,
                },
                Select: {
                    controlHeight: 40,
                    controlHeightLG: 42,
                    borderRadius: 16,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                },
            },
        }}
    >
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ConfigProvider>
```

Отрисовывает типографику не с 20px шрифтом, а дефолтным 14px. Почему это происходит и как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данный момент в 5 версии antd многие компоненты невозможно стилизовать. Вот ссылка на актуальный issue: [клик](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/38975)
Как вариант, можно создать глобальный класс типа .baseTypography и прописывать везде где нужно

Comment: Да, как вариант.

Сейчас работает так: можно глобальный font size token установить либо для каждого элемента typography через его API инлайн стили прописывать.